# gdal_translate of Tiff to gpkg with only one band

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, nodata, geopackage

I try to use gdal_translate in my windows command prompt to convert a single band .tif raster to a single band .gpkg.

```
gdal_translate -of GPKG example.tif example.gpkg
```

I always get a .gpkg with four bands.

I tried all possible combinations of the following commands with no succes:

```
-band
-mask
-expand
```

gdalinfo of example.tif

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: example.tif
       example.tif.aux.xml
Size is 5334, 5280
"
"
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
"
"
Band 1 Block=5334x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=10.000 Max=113.000
  Minimum=10.000, Maximum=113.000, Mean=50.602, StdDev=14.032
  NoData Value=255
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=113
    STATISTICS_MEAN=50.60229149027
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=10
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=14.032043952498
```

gdalinfo of example.gpkg:

```
Driver: GPKG/GeoPackage
Files: example.gpkg
Size is 5334, 5280
"
"
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  IDENTIFIER=example
  ZOOM_LEVEL=5
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
"
"
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Comment: Also please show us the exact commandline(s) you used.  with regards to the parameters. Please add the relevant bits from `gdalinfo` for both your input and the bad output.

Comment: Gdalinfo showes that the NoData value in the tiff was already 255. So this is no transforming issue. I updated my question acording to that.

Comment: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html#opening-options suggests that you could add -oo "BAND_COUNT=1" but how would we be able to find the *actual* count of bands is beyond me.

Comment: Try converting from Type=Byte to Type=Float when you save to GeoPackage, assuming the Type is not critical. GDAL seems to assume 4 bands when converting to GeoPackage for Int type data, and 1 band for Float type data. I don't know why though!